# Subdomain HTTP not available outside network

Tags: iis, rewrite, https, subdomain

I set up an http to https redirect for a subdomain using the url rewrite 2.0 module. Here's the web.config code.

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This redirect works within the network. In other words, store.domain.com redirects to https://store.domain.com. However, outside of the network, store.domain.com doesn't redirect, nor is it accessible at all. Inside of the network, https://store.domain.com is accessible.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you've got split DNS and need to add an external record. If you give us the domain, we could probably help you diagnose that.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense. store.crescentparts.com. Thanks.

Comment: DNS is resolving fine to 40.129.219.21. It's not responding, though. Do you have firewalls in place that would prevent access?

Comment: Yes, that was it. It was blocked at the firewall level. Thanks for your help!